# How to select rows which matches certain row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe below

```
A B
a0 1
b0 1
c0 2
a1 3 
b1 4
b2 3
```

First,If df.A startswith `"a"`,I would like to cut `df`.

`df[df.A.str.startswith("a")]`

```
A B
a0 1
a1 3
```

Therefore I would like to cut df like below.

`sub1`

```
A B
a0 1
b0 1
c0 2
```

`sub2`

```
A B
a1 3 
b1 4
b2 3
```

then I would like to extract rows whose column B number matches the rows whose column A startswith`"a"`

`sub1`

```
A B
a0 1
b0 1
```

`sub2`

```
A B
a1 3  
b2 3
```

then append.

`result`

```
A B
a0 1
b0 1
a1 3
b2 3
```

How can I cut and append `df` like this.

I tried `cut` method but didn't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with `mask` for creating `NaN` which are forward filled by `B` values with `ffill`:

*Notice is necessary values starts with `a` has to be first in each group for using `ffill`*

```
print (df.B.where(df.A.str.startswith("a")))
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: B, dtype: float64


print (df.B.where(df.A.str.startswith("a")).ffill())
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
Name: B, dtype: float64

df = df[df.B == df.B.where(df.A.str.startswith("a")).ffill()]
print (df)
    A  B
0  a0  1
1  b0  1
3  a1  3
5  b2  3
```